# Scala change data iniside 2D list and return new list

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming, immutability

If lets say I have

```
val ll : List[List[Int]] = List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6), List(7,8,9))
```

What I want to do is multiple each number inside my list with the next one. So a n to n+1 multiplication.

So after what I want to do Is multiple 1 by 4, 2 by 5, 3 by 6, 4 by 7, 5 by 8 and 6 by 9.

```
val x : List[List[Int]] = List(List(4,10,18), List(28,40,54))
```

I have tried sliding(2) but It didnt work. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, I think the best way is using a `foldLeft`

```
// we need to iterate on the list saving the previous element so we can use it for the multiplication. We start the iteration from the second element and we use the head as the first previous element
ll.tail.foldLeft((List[List[Int]](), ll.head)) {
   case ((res, last), elem) =>
     // here we calculate the multiplication
     val mult = elem.zip(last).map{
       case (v1, v2) => v1 * v2
     }
     // we add it to the result and we update the previous element
     (mult :: res, elem)
}._1.reverse
```

or with a `foldRight`

```
ll.dropRight(1).foldRight((List[List[Int]](), ll.last)) {
   case (elem, (res, last)) =>
     val mult = elem.zip(last).map{
       case (v1, v2) => v1 * v2
     }
     (mult :: res, elem)
}._1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you mind adding some comments or explanation to the code so I know what each line does.

Comment: I have added comments to the `foldLeft` solution, the `foldRight` is the same idea but in reverse order

Answer (score 2):

I have realized that it's much easier using `sliding`, as you proposed your question

```
ll.sliding(2).map{
    case List(l1, l2) => 
       l1.zip(l2).map{ 
          case (v1, v2)=> v1 * v2 
       }
}.toList
```

Comment: Oh I didnt do zip in my code as I didnt know what it does. Thank you once again